# Joomla 3 registration form

Tags: php, joomla

On one of the sites i need to do some changes on for a client i am having trouble finding something.

On the standard Joomla 3 registration system a custom field was added to the form, but that form does not email to the admin when someone registers, please can someone point me in the correct direction on where i can make that field be sent in the email.

I have looks on quite a few pages on the net but have not come right with any of the answers that i found. I have also tried going to most of the php files to see if i cant find something but i am not having much luck.

Comment: How was the extra field added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that email is hard coded; it is really a legacy from Joomla 1.0. What you would probably want to do is turn off the  core notification system and instead use a plugin that would be triggered with the `onUserAfterSave` event and use similar code to what is in the core. You will find that in the `activate($token)` method in the frontend registration model for com_users.

The `plugins/user/joomla` plugin gives an example of how to build an email, bit in your case you would want to build it when the user is created in the site application (isSite() == true).  You can also look at the `contactcreator` plugin in the same folder; it also uses the `onUserAfterSave` event.

Comment: Is there not a way to change the email that it can at least include the new field in the code?

Comment: Not that I am aware of (you could override the model completely but that seems way worse than writing a plugin). The whole thing should always have been a plugin but I suspect it predates plugins/mosbots and definitely that specific trigger.  Writing the plugin will take you about 30 minutes if you just copy an existing user plugin but us the save event instead. Look at contactcreator as the model; it uses the same event.  Your context variable will be `com_users.registration`.